# Understanding Ubuntu juju installed in Amazon Cloud

Tags: juju, amazon-ec2, aws, jenkins

I will explain, what I have:

1. I created an instance from Ubintu juju AMI from community AMIs.
2. I connected to this instance using `ssh`.
3. I would like to deploy a "charms" here, in my instance.
4. But, When I try to do "juju add-unit juju-gui" it says me:

   ```
   ERROR Could not find AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
   ```
5. also, I installed a juju client, configured it, tried to deploy a charm,
   but it creates a new instance every time for every deploy command.

I wonder, if you could explain me, how should I work with juju? I need to install Jenkins,and other dev tools in one instance.

Answer (score 3):

Typically a Juju instance is bootstrapped and managed from a client such as your local machine.

You will want to take a look at the documentation: https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/ and for configuring for aws: https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/help-aws

You may also want to take a look at `juju-quickstart` it's run from your local Ubuntu machine and deploys the Juju GUI as well onto the bootstrap node. The Juju GUI cannot *yet* however deploy using `--to` (see below)

Every time you run `juju deploy` or scale up a service Juju will, by default create a new instance.

To deploy to a single instance you use the `--to` option

`juju deploy mysql --to 23` where `23` is the machine number.

You can find the machine number in the `juju status` output.

You can find more information on deploy using `juju help deploy` from your local machine with the Juju client installed.